# Keep rows with same column characters as other df in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to have a df keeping the rows matching `'column'` Observations from `df2`

```
df <- data.frame(column=c("Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3", "Obs4", "Obs5"), S1 = c(1.4,1.9,1.3,2,1), S2= c(0.8,2,1,3,4), S3=c(2.4,2.1,0.5,2,3), S4=c(0.5,0.6,0.9,4,5), S5=c(1.4,1.3,1.6,3,3))

df2<- data.frame(column=c("Obs2", "Obs4"), X = c(1.4,1.9), Y= c(0.8,2))
```

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df3<- df %% keep rows which df$column observations are found in df2$column
```

To a final output:

```
  column S1  S2  S3  S4  S5
1 Obs2   1.9 2.0 2.1 0.6 1.3
2 Obs4   2.0 3.0 2.0 4.0 3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a semi-join:

```
df %>% semi_join(df2, by = "column")
#   column  S1 S2  S3  S4  S5
# 1   Obs2 1.9  2 2.1 0.6 1.3
# 2   Obs4 2.0  3 2.0 4.0 3.0
```

In case it's useful, the opposite is called an anti-join (and has an `anti_join` function) that keeps only rows that don't match.

Joining is more flexible than filtering because it can work if there are multiple columns to match on.

Comment: This a very useful function actually, thanks @gregor !

Answer (score 1):

Using filter:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(column %in% df2$column)
  column  S1 S2  S3  S4  S5
1   Obs2 1.9  2 2.1 0.6 1.3
2   Obs4 2.0  3 2.0 4.0 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`:

```
#Code
df3 <- df[df$column %in% df2$column,]
```

Output:

```
  column  S1 S2  S3  S4  S5
2   Obs2 1.9  2 2.1 0.6 1.3
4   Obs4 2.0  3 2.0 4.0 3.0
```

Or using `subset()`:

```
#Code2
df3 <- subset(df,column %in% df2$column)
```

Output:

```
  column  S1 S2  S3  S4  S5
2   Obs2 1.9  2 2.1 0.6 1.3
4   Obs4 2.0  3 2.0 4.0 3.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a simple code as well :)

Comment: @Ecg It is a pleasure helping you, I have included two `base R` options so that you can choose!

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R`

```
df[with(df, column %in% df2$column),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `match`

```
df[!is.na(match(df$column, df2$column)), ]
```

or `grepl`

```
df[which(grepl(paste(c(df2$column), collapse = "|"), df$column)), ]
```

---

```
 column  S1 S2  S3  S4  S5
2   Obs2 1.9  2 2.1 0.6 1.3
4   Obs4 2.0  3 2.0 4.0 3.0
```